# JS - Cant get this to point to callers this in handler of custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

The title might not be worded correctly. 
Basically I am testing with custom event handlers and got to the point where they are working, but the event handler's **this** points to the ControlClientSide instead of the item that triggered the event.

The code below will clarify everything:

```
function ControlClientSide()
{    
    this.CheckBoxClicked = function(e) { }        
    this.Configure = function() {        
        $('#checkBox100').change(function(e) { $(this).trigger("CheckBoxClicked"); }.bind(this));                
    };
    this.Configure();
};

var x = new ControlClientSide();
$(x).on("CheckBoxClicked", function(e) { alert( /* $(this).val() + */ ' Hi'); })
    .on("CheckBoxClicked", function(e) { alert( /* $(this).val() + */ ' Hi2'); });
```

In the two handlers I am trying to make this point to the actual checkbox item. Currently it is pointing at the ControlClientSide. Can anyone suggest what I am missing?

See the following JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/KC5RH/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want access to the checkbox that fired the event, just pass it as an additional parameter in your `triggerHandler` call.  Also, remove your `.bind(this)` call, it isn't needed in this scenario:

```
function ControlClientSide()
{    
    this.CheckBoxClicked = function() {  } 

    var thisControl = this;
    this.Configure = function() {        
        $('#checkBox100').change(function() { $(thisControl).triggerHandler("CheckBoxClicked", this);});   
    };
    this.Configure();
};
```

Then, you can access the element via a parameter in your listener:

```
$(x).on("CheckBoxClicked", function(obj, arg) {  alert( $(arg).attr("id") + ' Hi'); })
    .on("CheckBoxClicked", function(obj, arg) { alert( $(arg).attr("id") + ' Hi2'); });
```

See the fiddle for the complete working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/85qdH/4/

Comment: How come when try to get id in the handler ($(elem).attr("id")), it is coming up undefined?

Comment: If i console.log(this) in the handler is it coming back as: ControlClientSide {CheckBoxClicked: function, Configure: function, jQuery1101008445121021941304: Object}

Comment: Sorry, I originally missed a param.  Please see my updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly binding it to your object with `.bind(this)`. Also, you're setting the your object to listen to the event, not a DOM node. So, you need to remove the `bind(this)` part.

Then, use `trigger` instead of `triggerHandler` to have the event bubble up the DOM, so you can use delegation to capture it:

```
function ControlClientSide()
{    
    this.CheckBoxClicked = function() { }        
    this.Configure = function() {        
        $('#checkBox100').change(function() {
            $(this).trigger("CheckBoxClicked"); 
        });   
    };
    this.Configure();
};

var x = new ControlClientSide();
$(document).on("CheckBoxClicked", "input", function() { console.log(this); alert(this.id); })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KC5RH/9/

Comment: Im a little confused. "CheckBoxClicked" is not part of document

Comment: You were binding to the `ControlClientSide` instance.

Comment: This does not work in the JSFIDDLE. "CheckBoxClicked" event is not fired when checkbox is clicked

Comment: the console.log which is in the ControlClientSide works. the console.log in the handler outside of ControlClientSide does not work.

Comment: @BlueChameleon Wait, I just noticed something else: any special reason for triggerHandler instead of trigger? Docs say events fired with triggerHandler don't bubble up the DOM.

Comment: No specific reason for trigger/triggerHandler. What i dont understand in your example is doing $(document) instead of $(x). In my project I have an array of ControlClientSide and I will need to hook the CheckBoxClicked ONLY on certain instances. In your example, will CheckBoxClicked be called on all instances?

Comment: I'm using event delegation. You can also use `$('#checkBox100').on("CheckBoxClicked", function...)`. What you can't do is use `on` on an element that is not a DOM element (x is not).

Comment: That is not a problem with my example, you're triggering the event twice, one for cat and one for dog.

Comment: You CAN use on with element that is not a DOM element. A working jsfiddle is in my OP. The only problem with my OP is that the handler does not receive a pointer to the actual checkbox item.